# Can you hold payment/authorization for ActiveMerchant in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, activemerchant

I am using the activemerchant gem and I am trying to allow an user to make a payment for something, but not complete it until the seller authorizes the payment. I am using the paypal express option for Ruby 1.9.3 and rails 3.2.13.

I have it working right now to make a normal payment, but I can't figure how to hold the payment.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up an authorization at the time you send the customer over to PayPal, so instead of...

```
EXPRESS_GATEWAY.setup_purchase(total_in_cents, options)
```

You need to do...

```
EXPRESS_GATEWAY.setup_authorization(total_in_cents, options)
```

Use the authorize method of the paypal express module – instead of purchase – and save the authorization for when you need to capture the transaction.